# Like button like Follow (Twitter) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, facebook-like, twitter-follow

I added the following code to get a nice follow button for twitter:

```
 <a href="https://twitter.com/twitterid" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false" data-lang="en">Follow us @Twitter</a>
```

Is there a way to get a similar like button for facebook? I tried to configure it at [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), but I get the count with it, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to implement the code provided by Facebook in whole. Then, you can apply CSS styling that hides the count. Try this solution, via [Jacob Quatier](http://jacobquatier.com/posts/2013/04/01/facebook-like-buttons-without-count/):

```
/* CSS Hack for hiding the LIKE count */
div.fb-like span {
  display:block;
  width:48px !important;  
}

div.fb-like iframe {
  width:48px !important;
}

div.fb-like iframe.fb_iframe_widget_lift {
  width:450px !important;
}
```